# Can I play Day Z on My Raspberry Pi?

Tags: software-recommendation

I know I can play Minecraft on my raspberry pi, but is Day Z possible or would I need a gaming computer? Though I have a tight wallet ...

Answer (score 4):

We are able to play a version of Minecraft on the Raspberry Pi because the developers of Minecraft [ported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting) a version of the game to run on the Pi.

After doing some quick research on DayZ using Google; all indications show that DayZ is a Microsoft PC based game at this time.  There was some discussion about Bohemian Interactive supporting game consoles (XBox) in the future.

I recommend that you post your wishes for supporting a version of the game for the Raspberry Pi on the games [forum](http://forums.dayzgame.com/).

Answer (score 2):

DayZ is a Windows game. The raspberry pi does not run Windows. You will not be able to play Day Z on a raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi is not powerful enough to run Day Z and is also not a Windows machine, which Day Z requires.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using the Raspberry Pi as a gaming computer I would suggest using the [Retropie](http://blog.petrockblock.com/retropie/) distro.

Although I am unfamiliar with the game DayZ (I would guess zombies ...) you may find games for the retropie which satisfy your gaming needs.

Answer (score 0):

Download steam on your pi. You can remote play with your PC using the rapper pi as a display and controller